# When to use which registers?

Tags: assembly, mips

$t (temporaries) Caller saved if needed. Subroutines can use w/out saving. Not preserved across procedure calls.

$s (saved values) Callee saved. A subroutine using one of these must save original and restore it before exiting. Preserved across procedure calls.

When to use which registers? As far as I guess, when working with subroutines, we use $s registers, and, otherwise $t registers.

When to use $f registers?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$txx` as much as possible. Use `$sxx` for program state that needs to be preserved across calls. (A common bug and difficult to find bug is accidentally expecting a `$txx` register to have unchanged state across a call.)

The `$fxx` registers are for floating point use only. Do not use them for anything else - that way lies madness.